# Smooth scrolling page jump

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I need some help.

I tried to make a simple project on JSFiddle, but I can't get it to work.
http://jsfiddle.net/reUyp/2/

Here's the code

HTML:

```
<div id="img0">
    <b class="i01">ONE</b> <b class="i02">TWO</b>　<b class="i03">THREE</b>
</div>

<div style="width:200px; height:500px; background-color:red;" id="i01"></div>
<br>

<div style="width:200px; height:500px; background-color:blue;" id="i02"></div>
<br>

<div style="width:200px; height:500px; background-color:green;" id="i03"></div>
<br>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    $('#img0 b').click(function(){
        CL=$(this).attr('class')
        st=$('#'+CL+'').offset().top;       
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: st}, 500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

What I want is that when you click on one of the words, the page should scroll to the corresponding colored div. But it doesn't...

What am I missing? I'm sure it's a really stupid thing...

Oh, and is there actually a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: You forgot to include the jQuery library in the fiddle, here's an updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/reUyp/4/

Comment: you are using jQuery.. but havent loaded it in jsfiddle... select a jQuery version in "Frameworks and Extensions" in jsfiddle..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a silly mistake.

Comment: Ahahahah, I'm feeling so stupid right now! I knew it! Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery, you have to include it into your jsFiddle project. Select it in the top left corner and your sample will work.

Also in your own project you have to include jQuery with eg:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

inside the head part of the html page.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use jQuery syntax but haven't loaded jQuery in the `Frameworks & Extensions` sidebar. Select `jQuery 1.9.1` and your code works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

See this, this is your correct answer.

Fiddle [`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/reUyp/5/)